# differential equation problem: solving for constants in implicit solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question with respect to finding implicit solutions and the constants.

Suppose I have a problem where $x' = \frac{1}{3x^2+1}$ and $x(0) = 1$ and I want to find the implicit solution.

Solving it gives $x^3 + x = t + c$. So in this case, to find the constant corresponding to the initial condition, would I just substitute 1's such that it becomes:

$(1)^3 + 1 = 0 + c$ and that $c = 2$? Or is this a misconception that I am having ?

It would be nice if someone could confirm this for me.

Thank you.

Comment: The $C$ that you get in an implicit solution form generally is *not* the same as the $C$ you would get when solving the explicit solution using ICs. However, both constants that arise from either solution method will bring you to an equivalent solution with the given initial condition. You need to indicate what your solution form is if the problem doesn't tell you (i.e., "Find the *implicit* solution of $x(t)$ = \cdots$")

Comment: So what would be the approach to finding $C$ in the example that I gave ?